# Access to Steam community groups via API

Tags: php, api, vbulletin, steam

I'm currently trying display events from a Steam community group on a forum (running vBulletin 4.2.1). I've looked at the Steam API's and none of the ones I can find give much access to groups, the most they seem able to do is to display a members list.

Is there an API which allows you to retrieve steam group events? or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not an API for this (yet), but you are able to get this information via the XML that Valve makes available.

First, you need to know your group's `groupID64` value. You can find this by examining the XML of a member of your group.

Using [Robin Walker](http://www.valvesoftware.com/company/people.html) as an example, we can look at his profile using this URL:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/id/robinwalker/?xml=1
```

In that XML, you'll find that he is a member of several groups. Each of them have a line like this:

```
<groupID64>103582791429521412</groupID64>
```

That value is what we need. That value is used in a URL like this to pull events by month

```
 http://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791429521412/events?xml=1&action=eventFeed&month=$month&year=$year
```

Where `$month` and `$year` are numerical values (ie. `1` and `2014` for January, 2014)

This will return XML that looks like this if there are no events for the month:

```
<response>
    <results>OK</results>
    <bPastMonth>0</bPastMonth>
    <monthName>January</monthName>
    <year>2014</year>
    <eventCount>0</eventCount>
    <expiredEventCount>0</expiredEventCount>
</response>
```

Or this for expired events:

```
<response>
    <results>OK</results>
    <bPastMonth>1</bPastMonth>
    <monthName>December</monthName>
    <year>2013</year>
    <expiredEvent eventID="1387405180685446058">                <div class="eventBlock" id="1387405180685446058_eventBlock">
                    <div class="eventLeftBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="eventDateBlock"><span class="hiliteTextRed">Sunday 22</span><br /><span class="eventDateTime">10:26am</span></div>
                    <div class="eventBlockIcon">
                        <div class="playerAvatar"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tf2scrap#events/1387405180685446058"><img src="http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/e3f595a92552da3d664ad00277fad2107345f743.jpg" /></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="eventBlockTitle"><a class="headlineLink" href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tf2scrap#events/1387405180685446058">Christmas Event!</a><br />
                        <span class="eventSmallText"></span>
                    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tf2scrap#events/1387405180685446058">280 comments...</a>
                    </div>
                    <br clear="left" />
                </div></expiredEvent>
    <eventCount>0</eventCount>
    <expiredEventCount>1</expiredEventCount></response>
```

Or this for upcoming events:

```
<response>
    <results>OK</results>
    <bPastMonth>0</bPastMonth>
    <monthName>January</monthName>
    <year>2014</year><event eventID="1371642583203021771">              <div class="eventBlock" id="1371642583203021771_eventBlock">
                <div class="eventLeftBlock">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="eventDateBlock"><span class="">Friday 10</span><br /><span class="eventDateTime">11:00am</span></div>
                <div class="eventBlockIcon">
                    <div class="playerAvatar"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamlug#events/1371642583203021771"><img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/skin_1/eventIcon_ChatEvent.jpg" /></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="eventBlockTitle"><a class="headlineLink" href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamlug#events/1371642583203021771">SteamLUG Cast S02E01</a><br />
                    <span class="eventSmallText"></span>
                <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamlug#events/1371642583203021771">0 comments...</a>
                </div>
                <br clear="left" />
            </div></event>
    <eventCount>1</eventCount>
    <expiredEventCount>0</expiredEventCount>
</response>
```

`event` and `expiredEvent`s can be in the same XML and the `eventCount` and `expiredEventCount` will reflect the total number of each that appear in the XML.